# Faster way to find Nth prime

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

I'm recently trying to go through a list of 100 various exercises in my book, this is currently number 23. Find the Nth prime number, while this seems quite easy, I noticed it takes a long time to search for larger numbers (aka 50000 takes around 47 seconds already.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;
bool checkPrime(int n);

int main()
{   
    while (true)
    {       
        register int number;
        cin >> number;
        register int counter = 0;
        register int numbers = 0;
        time_t start = clock();
        while (counter < number)
        {
            numbers++;
            if (checkPrime(numbers))counter++;
        }
        double time_diff = (clock() - start);
        cout << numbers << endl;
        cout << "Time needed to process in ms: " << time_diff << endl;
    }
}


bool checkPrime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return false;
    for (register int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
        if (n%i == 0)return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

this is the code itself, nothing too fancy as it's still one of the easier exercises, tried setting the variables as a register as I heard it'd make things faster at times. WolframAlpha needs around 10 seconds to check the 100.000th prime, my code here takes around 90. Thanks in advance, Folling

Comment: A sieve of Eratosthenes is a common method to find all reasonably small primes up to some limit. Look it up, it's very likely to be faster than your current implementation.

Comment: hint: your `checkPrime` is O(n), it could be **easily** made O(sqrt(n)). (n here being the number n, not its number of bits)

Comment: @moreON is correct — I wrote a C program a while back that solves this problem using the sieve of Etatosthenes. It takes about 16 milliseconds to find the 100,000th prime, and less than 0.2 seconds to find the millionth. You can use the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) to calculate the required size of your number sieve.

Comment: Do you have any space limitation?

Comment: This has been discussed so many times...

Comment: Anyway, everybody is obsessed with `checkPrime` function here. But another thing you can do is to start with the number 3 and change `numbers++;` to `numbers += 2;` in your `main` function. It won't give you a 2x boost because all those numbers that you'll skip are easy to check, but it will give you a few percent performance improvement.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have space limitation, create a vector that contains the primes and change your `checkPrime` method as follows:

```
vector<int> primes;
bool checkPrime(int n) {
     if (n <= 1) return false;
     for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(), primes.at(i) <= sqrt(n); i++) {

          if (n%primes.at(i)== 0)
               return false;
     }
     primes.push_back(n)
     return true;
}
```

By this technique, you will only check if n is divisible by a prime instead of all numbers upto its square root.

Here, we leverage that a number is either prime or multiple of one or more primes.

CheckPrime method is `O(log n)`, so finding first N primes is `O(n log n)` where n is the value of Nth prime

Answer (score 2):

If you need the nth prime number calculate it very fast. This code fo you
Two algorithms used for this

1. First algorithm is Meisel-Lehmer (Meisel-Lehmer very fast calculate count of prime number from 1 to n )
2. Second algorithm is a binary search

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
typedef long long ll;
using namespace std;
const int N = 1e6 + 2;
bool np[N];
int prime[N], pi[N];

int getprime() {
    int cnt = 0;
    np[0] = np[1] = true;
    pi[0] = pi[1] = 0;
    for (int i = 2;i < N;++i) {
        if (!np[i]) prime[++cnt] = i;
        pi[i] = cnt;
        for (int j = 1;j <= cnt && i * prime[j] < N;++j) {
            np[i * prime[j]] = true;
            if (i % prime[j] == 0) break;
        }
    }
    return cnt;
}
const int M = 7;
const int PM = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17;
int phi[PM + 1][M + 1], sz[M + 1];
void init() {
    getprime();
    sz[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0;i <= PM;++i) phi[i][0] = i;
    for (int i = 1;i <= M;++i) {
        sz[i] = prime[i] * sz[i - 1];
        for (int j = 1;j <= PM;++j) {
            phi[j][i] = phi[j][i - 1] - phi[j / prime[i]][i - 1];
        }
    }
}
int sqrt2(long long x) {
    long long r = (long long)sqrt(x - 0.1);
    while (r * r <= x) ++r;
    return int(r - 1);
}
int sqrt3(long long x) {
    long long r = (long long)cbrt(x - 0.1);
    while (r * r * r <= x) ++r;
    return int(r - 1);
}
long long getphi(long long x, int s) {
    if (s == 0) return x;
    if (s <= M) return phi[x % sz[s]][s] + (x / sz[s]) * phi[sz[s]][s];
    if (x <= prime[s] * prime[s]) return pi[x] - s + 1;
    if (x <= prime[s] * prime[s] * prime[s] && x < N) {
        int s2x = pi[sqrt2(x)];
        long long ans = pi[x] - (s2x + s - 2) * (s2x - s + 1) / 2;
        for (int i = s + 1;i <= s2x;++i) {
            ans += pi[x / prime[i]];
        }
        return ans;
    }
    return getphi(x, s - 1) - getphi(x / prime[s], s - 1);
}
long long getpi(long long x) {
    if (x < N) return pi[x];
    long long ans = getphi(x, pi[sqrt3(x)]) + pi[sqrt3(x)] - 1;
    for (int i = pi[sqrt3(x)] + 1, ed = pi[sqrt2(x)];i <= ed;++i) {
        ans -= getpi(x / prime[i]) - i + 1;
    }
    return ans;
}
long long lehmer_pi(long long x) {
    if (x < N) return pi[x];
    int a = (int)lehmer_pi(sqrt2(sqrt2(x)));
    int b = (int)lehmer_pi(sqrt2(x));
    int c = (int)lehmer_pi(sqrt3(x));
    ll sum = getphi(x, a) + ll((b + a - 2) * (b - a + 1)) / 2;
    for (int i = a + 1;i <= b;i++) {
        ll w = x / prime[i];
        sum -= lehmer_pi(w);
        if (i > c) continue;
        ll lim = lehmer_pi(sqrt2(w));
        for (int j = i;j <= lim;j++) {
            sum -= lehmer_pi(w / prime[j]) - (j - 1);
        }
    }
    return sum;


}


//32000000000 ---1382799415 count
//25000000000 ---1091987405 count
//23000000000 ---1008309544 count
int main() {
    init();
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(0);cout.tie(0);
    long long n, l, r, res = 0;
    cin >> n;
    l = n;
    if (n == 1)cout << 2;
    else {
        l = 2;
        r = 23000000000;
        while (l < r) {
            ll k = (l + r) / 2, s = lehmer_pi(k);
            if (s >= n) { r = k; }
            else if (s < n) { l = k + 1; }
        }
        cout << r;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
inline bool checkPrime(int n,std::vector<int>);

int main()
{
    int number,counter,numbers;
    std:cout<<"Prime Searcher";
    std::vector<int> sieve;


    while (true)
    {

        cin >> number;
        counter = 0;
        numbers = 0;
        time_t start = clock();
        while (counter < number)
        {
            if (numbers>2){
                numbers+=2;
            }
            else{
                numbers++;
            }
            if (checkPrime(numbers,sieve)){
                sieve.push_back(numbers);
                counter++;
            }

            }
        double time_diff = (clock() - start);
        cout << numbers << endl;
        cout << "Time needed to process in seconds: " << time_diff/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    }
}


inline bool checkPrime(int n, std::vector<int> sieve) {
    double numPrimes=(sqrt(n)/log(sqrt(n))+3);
    if (numPrimes>sieve.size()){numPrimes=sieve.size();}
    if (n <= 1) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i < numPrimes; i++) {
        if (n%sieve[i] == 0)return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

By my benchmarking, this is an over 2x optimization for n=4000, and increases with higher numbers. `register` is depreciated. Any advice about how to further optimize would be appreciated. At n=50000, it takes 24 seconds on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

this is good method for your exercise and for very big numbers

```
bool chekPrime(unsigned long long int n){
int flag=0;            //flag=0 => flag is not set
if(n<=1||n%2==0)flag=1;//flag=1 => n is not prime
if(n==2||n==3)flag=2;  //flag=2 => n is prime
if(flag==0){
    for(unsigned long long int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2){
        if(n%i==0){
            flag=1;//flag=1 => n is not prime
            break;
        }
    }
}
//if flag not set or flag=2 => n is prime
if(flag==0||flag==2)return true;
else return false;
```

}